# viewpager implemented in gridview position

Tags: android

I am working on an application that have to have a `GridView` in the main activity containing images.

When an image is clicked, it has to open in another `Activity` in a bigger size. In this `Activity`, a `ViewPager` has to be implemented so that I can swipe right and left to change between the images.

The problem is that when i click on an image, the first image of the images appear firstly (argentina flag) and then the viewpager works .. how can i make it start by the image that i clicked ?

This is my main activity code :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;

public class MainActivityPager extends ActionBarActivity
{
    static int[] FLAG;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    PagerAdapter adapter;
    GridView gridview;
    int count;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_pager);

         FLAG = new int[] { R.drawable.flag_of_argentina, R.drawable.flag_of_brazil,
                    R.drawable.flag_of_england, R.drawable.flag_of_france,
                    R.drawable.flag_of_germany, R.drawable.flag_of_italy, R.drawable.flag_of_spain,
                    R.drawable.flag_of_uruguay };

         AdapterGrid adapter = new AdapterGrid(MainActivityPager.this, FLAG);
         gridview = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
         gridview.setAdapter(adapter);

         gridview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                    long id)
            {
                Intent intent = new Intent(view.getContext(), ActivityImage.class);
                intent.putExtra("position", position);
                count = gridview.getCount();
                intent.putExtra("count", count);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

This is my AdapterGrid class code :

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class AdapterGrid extends BaseAdapter
{
    private int[] mFlag;
    private Context mContext;

    public AdapterGrid(Context context, int[] flag) {
        //super(context, flag);
        mContext = context;
        mFlag = flag;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFlag.length;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View grid;
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
        {
            grid = new View(mContext);
            grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_single, null);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView)grid.findViewById(R.id.grid_image);
            imageView.setImageResource(mFlag[position]);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        return grid;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

}
```

This is my ActivityImage code :

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.Menu;

public class ActivityImage extends FragmentActivity
{
    private static int COUNT;
    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        COUNT = intent.getExtras().getInt("count");
        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        mPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    }

    public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
            super(fragmentManager);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return COUNT;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
           return FragmentImage.init(position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_image, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is my FragmentImage class code :

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

public class FragmentImage extends Fragment {
    int fragVal;

    static FragmentImage init(int pos) {
        FragmentImage frag = new FragmentImage();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("val", pos);
        frag.setArguments(args);
        return frag;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        fragVal = getArguments() != null ? getArguments().getInt("val") : 1;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View layoutView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_image, container,
                false);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) layoutView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        imageView.setImageResource(MainActivityPager.FLAG[fragVal]);

        return layoutView;
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the position intent.putExtra("position", position); but never use it.
get it and
set after
`mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
mPager.setCurrentItem(CurrentPosition);`